# Byte representation - Network raw data

Tags: c++, networking, architecture, byte, winsock

I'm a little confused on the following network analogy:

Consider I'm serializing a structure (with integers) by passing a pointer to the Winsock send() function.

These 4byte integers on my Intel machine may be represented in a different way on a big endian machine and misinterpreted when the structure is recreated on the other side.

That's understandable, but a problem - so I was wondering - what if both programs that run on both machines are compiled as 32bit? Wouldn't an automatic conversion occur from intel <-> AMD instruction set just as it happens for binary files?

If there's no way to avoid it - how would I work with sending raw data structures over the network without having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose a network format for you data and specify every byte in this format (e.g. you may use big-endian 4 bytes representation for integers), and then write converters to/from this format for each kind of platform your program runs at.

The 32/64-bits, instruction sets, Intel/AMD differences have nothing to do with this.

Comment: That's exactly what he means.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at book [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) he explaining this problem and its easy solutions very clearly. Even though the code which he gave for **UNIX** by changing API calls you can do this in **WinSock**. If you are lazy to read like me check this [Packing Data](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#serialization)

Answer (score 0):

Because machines of DIFFERENT architectures (no, Intel and AMD don't have [sufficiently] different architectures) may store data in different byte-order. Since people using networking want their data to arrive in a format that is understood, whether is a Digital Equipment VAX from 1990, a Sun Sparc from 2005 or a AMD 486 from 1996, a 2008 iPhone (ARM) or a 2013 Intel CoreX machine, the network protocol stipulates that the order should be in a certain way.

Since in the 1980-1990's, the most common machines (those that was likely to be connected to some sort of network, at least) happened to be "big endian", this was the choice made then, and of course, we can't change it now just because times have changed, because that would require ripping up all existing code that relies on the order being what it is.

Of course, if you ONLY send data to other machines using only YOUR software, then you can do what you like - it's your data, your method of packing it and your software. As long as both ends have the same idea of which order to use. If you want to send data to a protocol that isn't your own, then you need to follow what that protocol states with regards to byte order.

And it really is just a matter of "custom". We have to have a standard, otherwise we can't send data between machines of different fundamental architectures. Just like it would play havoc with most peoples ability to drive a car if different manufacturers (or models) put the brake pedal in different place depending on "what they felt like at the time" - imagine having to remember whether you should put your foot on the left, middle or right pedal to go slower?